# Few questions about constructors in C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor, multiple-constructors

In C# regarding the inheritance of constructors:

1. I have read that constructors cannot be inherited.
2. If the base class contains a constructor, one or more, the derived class have to always call one of them? It is not possible that the derived class can skip the constructor of the base class?
3. Derived class can have its own constructor but it has to call one of the base class constructors.

Are these statements corrects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Yes, you're right, constructors are not inherited. So just because `Object` has a parameterless constructor, that doesn't mean that `String` has a parameterless constructor, for example. From section 1.6.7.1 of the C# 4 spec:

   > Unlike other members, instance constructors are not inherited, and a class has no instance constructors other than those actually declared in the class. If no instance constructor is supplied for a class, then an empty one with no parameters is automatically provided.
2. Yes, the constructor chain of a derived class constructor will always go through its base class constructor... although it may be indirectly, as it could chain to another constructor in the same class via `this(...)` instead of `base(...)`. If you don't specify either `this(...)` or `base(...)`, that's equivalent to `base()` - calling the parameterless constructor in the base class.

See my [article on constructor chaining](http://pobox.com/%7Eskeet/csharp/constructors.html) for more information.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you, though I am not sure if I get it. If I declare a constructor in base class, according to the spec it will not be used by derived class.

Comment: @JeffreyZ: It will be used by the derived class if a derived class constructor calls it, either implicitly (if it's a parameterless base class constructor and the derived class constructor doesn't specify `this(...)` or `base(...)`) or explicitly (through a direct call to `base(...)`). If you could edit your question with a complete example which is confusing you, that would help. (Your third question is currently somewhat odd, too... you may want to edit it at the same time.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Oh right,also I need to call it explicitly or implicitly, but the base class constructor will alwayss be used, correct?

Comment: @JeffreyZ: *A* base class constructor will always be used, yes.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Hope I got it. So derived class can have its own constructors, but still on of the the base ones will be called.

Comment: @JeffreyZ: Yes - the base class constructor will be executed before the body of the derived class constructor.

Comment: Is there a way to construct an ancestor class deeper than the first class without adding that same constructor signature to every class in between?  I have an auto-generated EF class that inherits another EF class, but it's too lazy to provide all the ancestor's constructors that I need.  Editing the intermediate, auto-generated code to include them every time it's generated is getting to become a nuisance.

Comment: @fartwhif: If it generates partial classes, you can add the constructor in a separate file rather than editing the generated one. But no, there's no way of saying "derived classes should have a constructor with the same signature"

Answer (score 1):

**1.**  You **cannot** inherit constructors, but you **can** chain constructors.  Example:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
  public DerivedClass(object arg):base(arg){}
}
```

**2.**  Yes, for example, you cannot instantiate a class derived from an object with all private constructors *(except in the particular scenario that Jon mentions below in his comment)*.  You cannot skip the constructor of a base class, but you can have multiple overloads, and select the constructor you choose to use.

**3.**  Yes,  not sure what the question is here.

Comment: Point 1 is definitely true. Constructors are *not* inherited.

Comment: In #1 you are _chaining_ constructors, not inheriting them.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what was meant by inheriting the constructor.  How would you describe what I wrote in my answer, if its not inheriting? ahh chaining...okay thanks

Comment: Calling? You can't construct a DerivedClass, without giving it a constructor, i.e. you can't inherit the base constructor and use that instead.

Comment: @Jon, @Oded, @forsvarir - better?

Comment: @smartcavemean: Yes, downvote removed. Although for point two, you *can* create a class derived from one with only private constructors, if the derived class is nested in the base class - that way it gets access to the private members of the base class, including constructors.

Comment: @Jon, @Oded, What would it mean for constructors to be inherited?  Are there languages where this is a feature?

Comment: You just show that constructors are not inherited, hence you need to write new constructor with the same signature in derived class instead. However, parameterless constructors are inherited in C# (or automagically created by compiler, I'm not so sure what really happens behind the scene.)

Comment: @tia: Parameterless constructors are *not* inherited. The compiler generates a parameterless constructor (calling a base class parameterless constructor) if you don't specify *any* constructors.

Answer (score 0):

1 Yes

2 You cannot skip constructor but I think you could do nothing in default constructor. Just like

```
public class PClass {

    protected PClass() {
        // do nothing
    }

    public PClass(int myIntArg) {
        // initialize the class
    }

}

public Class CClass : PClass {

    public CClass(string myStringArg) : base() {
        // initialize the class
    }

}
```

3 Yes. See my previous example.